# Requests posts with Python

Tags: python, python-requests

This is the first time I am trying `requests.post()` because I have always used `requests.get()`. So I'm trying to navigate to a website and search. I am using yellowpages.com, and before I get negative feedback about using the site to scrape or about an API, I just want to try it out. The problem I am running into is that it spits out some html that isn't remotely what I am looking for. I'll post my code below to show you what I am talking about.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com"
search_terms = "Car Dealership"
location = "Jackson, MS"
q = {'search_terms': search_terms, 'geo_locations_terms': location}
page = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=q)

print(page.text)
```

Comment: Why are you using `params=q`?  `data=q` is the usual way of submitting post data.

Answer (score 2):

Your request boils down to

```
$ curl -X POST \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36' \
  'https://www.yellowpages.com/?search_terms=Car Dealership&geo_locations_terms=Jackson, MS'
```

For this the server returns a [`502 Bad Gateway`](https://httpstatuses.com/502) status code.

The reason is that you use `POST` together wihy query parameters `params`. The two don't go well together. Use [`data`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) instead:

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=q)
```

Comment: I’m not too familiar with curl. I’ll try this when I get back home this evening. Would I be using this with requests or alone?

Comment: Still not working. I keep getting an error when I try to use the `requests.post()` and `requests.get()` methods. However, when I add the URL manually, I have no problems getting the page to load in python. Something is getting messed up when I try to post the search terms and location then pass that info through. Any ideas?